# Git: remove commits for replaced files from history

Tags: git

I'm quite new to git and so some cruft and errors have accumulated in my repository. Now I wanted to clean it up again.

My situation is the following. I have added pictures to my repository but in a too high resolution. I replaced them later on with smaller versions, but they are still there in my history. I'm the only one who ever worked on that repository, so the problems of rewriting the history can be tolerated. My problem is that I have done other commits between adding the pictures and replacing them. Is this possible? If yes then how?

To illustrate it a little bit more what I have:

```
04f9ac3 replace big pictures with small pictures
503c2b6 make a useful commit
8ab463d add big picutres
3d2a5a5 initial commit
```

And what I'd like to achieve:

```
XXXXXXX combined commit of the "add big pictures" and "replace with small pictures"
503c2b6 make a useful commit
3d2a5a5 initial commit
```

I found a lot about "squashing" commits but if I understood it correctly it combines "neighbouring" commits together.  What I want to do is more to select certain commits and combine them. I hope that makes sense to anyone. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git rebase --interactive` to get an interactive rebase, where you can reorder commits and squash them. You'd invoke it like `git rebase -i 3d2a5a5` and you'll probably see something like

```
pick 8ab463d add big picutres
pick 503c2b6 make a useful commit
pick 04f9ac3 replace big pictures with small pictures
```

You can now edit this list, so it looks like

```
pick 8ab463d add big picutres
squash 04f9ac3 replace big pictures with small pictures
pick 503c2b6 make a useful commit
```

When you save this file and let the rebase start, it will add the "big picutres" commit, then squash in the "replace" commit, and give you an editor to rewrite the commit message of this squashed commit. After you save that message, it will then add the "make a useful commit" on top of this.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that you can reorder commits but actually that's just what I wanted. If I would have read the git messages more thoroughly I should have figured it out by myself. :) But somtimes you just need that pointer. Thanks again for your helpful and fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

You want to squash, you were right.  HOWEVER, you cannot squash the first commit in the rebase. :(

```
$ git log
04f9ac3 replace big pictures with small pictures
503c2b6 make a useful commit
8ab463d add big picutres
3d2a5a5 initial commit

$ git rebase -i 3d2a5a5    <--- Choose a commit BEFORE the one you don't want
squash 8ab463d             <--- First commit in rebase cannot be squashed :(
pick 503c2b6
pick 04f9ac3
```